# Pygame mouse hold

Tags: python, pygame

I am designing an incremental/clicker game in pygame, and I want to change the $ counter by 1 every click. However, I can hold the button down, and I can't find a way to limit this.

My button class is below:

```
class Button(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.rect=(x,y,width,height)
        self.image=pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,(self.rect),)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
    def check(self):
        mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.x+self.width >mouse[0] > self.x and self.y+self.height >mouse[1] > self.y:   
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]==True:
                return True
```

Is there a way to stop the button from being held down?

All help is appreciated!

Full code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

light_gray=(211,211,211)
black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def drawText(text, font, screen, x, y,color):
    textobj = font.render(text,True, color)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect(center=(x,y))
    screen.blit(textobj, textrect)

class Button(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.rect=(x,y,width,height)
        self.image=pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,(self.rect),)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
    def check(self):
        mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.x+self.width >mouse[0] > self.x and self.y+self.height >mouse[1] > self.y:   
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]==True:
                return True

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,50)

screen_width=1300
screen_height=700
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption('Clicker')

done=False

money=0

sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()

button=Button(25,screen_height-125,500,100,light_gray)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                terminate()

    if button.check()==True:
        money+=1

    screen.fill(light_gray)

    sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,button.rect, 3)
    text_width, text_height=font.size('Click!')
    drawText('Click!', font,screen,button.x+button.width/2,button.y+button.height/2,black)  

    drawText('$'+str(money),font,screen,screen_width/2,25,black)  

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(15)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the `button.check()` call to the event loop, it gets called only once per mouse click instead of every frame.

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if button.check():
                money += 1
```

I also recommend using a `pygame.Rect` in the `Button` class, then you can simply call the `pygame.Rect.collidepoint` method to see if the mouse collides with the button.

```
class Button(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.image=pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,(self.rect),)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height

    def check(self):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` can be problematic if you want to use it with buttons, because it only checks if a mouse button is held down and not if it was just clicked once.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

In your `button.check()` if statement it should add one to money and then wait until the mouse is not clicked:

```
if button.check()==True:
     money+=1
     while pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]==True:
         clock.tick(10)
```

Is that right?

Comment: `while` loop in PyGame (or any GUI) is not good idea. It stops other important elements in program - so program may freeze.. Besides if you don't get events from system then it may not update data which you get with `get_pressed()`

Comment: How can I implement that into my program?